# Dart performance: best approach for thousands of low-level IO operations

Tags: performance, dart, async-await, io

I have a Dart performance design/architecture question, which I realize may not have a clear-cut answer.

I'm working on a Git implementation in Dart, that needs to be fast (low latency, high throughput), as I'm going to use it to query Git Packs with hundreds of thousands of records (Pack = internal git file that stores files as deltas of other files, and zlib-compressed).

- Most of the IO load will be thousands of small read operations across one or more of these pack files.
- CPU load will consist of decompressing the data, and concatenating small chunks into larger UInt8Lists (still mostly less than 1KByte)
- Some of these operations may be parallellizable (decompression, processing of unrelated objects).
  Some processing could happen while waiting for IO.

My dilemma is as follows..
Should I implement "everything" (including all low level IO operations, and cpu limited operations) with async/await?
Will this give me a performance boost or make it easier to parallelize things in the future?
Or will there be a significant overhead cost, and should I rather make most low-level operations Synchronous, and parallelize on a high level with Isolates where possible?

I noticed as many people point out that 'async' is contagious, and slowly all my functions now have 'async' in the name, so it will be costly to make everything sync again later.
Thats why I want to make an informed decision at this point.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `async` is contagious, but that's not a negative so much as a necessary evil. Everything that is asynchronous is done by necessity: if a resource is asynchronous, then everything that depends on it also has to be asynchronous since you have no choice but to wait until the resource is available. There isn't really a simple way to synchronously access a resource that is asynchronous in nature, and trying to do so is usually an indication of code smell. (Even the `File.readXSync` methods are fairly smelly for non-trivial applications.)

Comment: If you want to go down this route in pure Dart, you have two choices: `async` or isolates. I can't speak to the performance of `async`, but since the execution of that is queue-based, putting hundreds of thousands of futures in the async queue probably would bog down your program. Isolates have a similar conundrum, but they at least have the benefit of not affecting the performance of your main thread (though you will have to figure out how to communicate back and forth efficiently since isolates don't share memory with the main thread).

Comment: A third solution you might want to look into is [Dart FFI](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/c-interop) which allows you to run native C modules from Dart. It's pretty experimental right now, but if you absolutely want the best performance metrics possible, that's probably your best bet.